# How to save progress from scraping reddit data as database file using python

Tags: python, pandas, reddit, praw

I wrote a script for getting some posts from reddit.

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='*******', \
                     client_secret='*******', \
                     user_agent='**********', \
                     username='********', \
                     password='*******8')
subreddit1 = reddit.subreddit("Tea")
subreddit2 = reddit.subreddit("Biophysics")
top_subreddit1 = subreddit1.top(limit=500)
top_subreddit2 = subreddit2.top(limit=500)
topics_dict = { "title":[],
                "score":[],
                "id":[], "url":[], 
                "comms_num": [],
                "created": [],
                "body":[]}
for submission1 in top_subreddit1:
    topics_dict["title"].append(submission1.title)
    topics_dict["score"].append(submission1.score)
    topics_dict["id"].append(submission1.id)
    topics_dict["url"].append(submission1.url)
    topics_dict["comms_num"].append(submission1.num_comments)
    topics_dict["created"].append(submission1.created)
    topics_dict["body"].append(submission1.selftext)
for submission2 in top_subreddit2:
    topics_dict["title"].append(submission2.title)
    topics_dict["score"].append(submission2.score)
    topics_dict["id"].append(submission2.id)
    topics_dict["url"].append(submission2.url)
    topics_dict["comms_num"].append(submission2.num_comments)
    topics_dict["created"].append(submission2.created)
    topics_dict["body"].append(submission2.selftext)
topics_data = pd.DataFrame(topics_dict)
topics_data
```

But it only displays in my jupyter.
Now I want to save progress as a database file. All advice are appreciated.

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping. 'Scrapping' means throwing away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. I'll present two, each with their pros and cons:

**1. CSV**

Simply  save your file to a .csv using [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
topics_data.to_csv('path_to_file.csv')
```

You can then proceed to parse this csv file in your client application, i.e., whatever application is going to use your scraped data.

Pros

- Simple to save
- Very barebones; further processing would be simple

Cons

- Very barebones; if you need any sort of structure, you won't have any flexibility

**2. SQLITE**

You can also opt to store the dataframe in sqlite using [DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
import sqlite3

db_file = 'my.db'
# This creates a new database file if it doesn't exist
db_conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
# This creates a new table 'topics_data' if it doesn't exist
topics_data.to_sql('topics_data', con=db_conn)
```

Pros

- Might be easier to parse for your client
- SQL is a very strong query language. You can take advantage of this

Cons

- Could be overkill if all you need is basic data transfer

Find out more about sqlite here: [sqlite tutorial](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/)

Answer (score 0):

To save data locally for internal python use later you can use the [built in pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

```
import pickle

def save_obj(obj, name ):
    with open(f'{name}.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def load_obj(name):
  try:
    with open(f'{name}.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
    print("")
    print(f"loaded {name}")
    print("")
  except Exception as e:
    print("")
    print(f"Error loading object '{name}': {e}")
    print("")
```